# Updating AD groups for students in each grade level

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a bunch of groups that contain a nested group.

Example:

> group "DElA 12th Grade" < currently contains group "Helena Class of
>   2018" group "DELA 11th Grade" < currently contains group "Helena Class
>   of 2019"

This is the case for many locations with nested groups k -12 each year on after 7. I want to change the nested groups for the next school year. I am using a `foreach` statement to run through the groups and an attribute flag to determine if the `groupmember` needs to be updated.

I am using switch statement to evaluate each location then a nested switch statement for each location to evaluate the Grade.

I believe what I have will work, but is there a cleaner more elegant way that I can look to do this?

Any advice would be great! The switch statements are toward the bottom, but I wanted to include all to hopefully help make sense what I am doing.

```
    #This updates the student groups. there are two kinds of groups 
    #1."Class of" groups and they contain the student objects.
    #2."Student Email Groups" these contain the nested "Class of" groups
    #the goal is on 7-1 update all groups descriptions 
    #and change the nested groups to the new school year
    #example the "DHCS 12th Grade" change the nested group from 2018 to 2019
    #once the Class of 2019 becomes 12th graders
    #I use the: 
    #    ExtensionAttribute1 for the year of graduation 
    #    ExtensionAttribute2 for the current Grade 
    #    ExtensionAttribute3 for the updated after 7-1 flag



    #region Set Current School year
    #This gets the current date and evaluates if after July1 

    [int]$currentmonth = Get-Date -UFormat %m
    [int]$currentyear = Get-Date -UFormat %Y
    $yearchange = if ($currentmonth -le 7) { 0 } else { 1 }
    $currentschoolyear = ($currentYear + $yearchange)

    #endregion



#region This works with the "Class of" groups: Sets the desription, ExtAtt2


$ClassGroups = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase  `
"ou=student groups,ou=groups,ou=kippdelta,dc=deltacollegeprep,dc=org" -filter * -Properties * |   `
Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "CN=*,ou=Student email groups,ou=*" }|
select Name, description, extensionattribute2, extensionAttribute1


foreach ($group in $classGroups)
{
$TempYear = $currentschoolyear
If      ($group.extensionattribute1 -lt $TempYear) {$TempClass = 'Alumni'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -like $TempYear) {$TempClass = '12th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '11th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '10th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '9th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '8th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '7th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '6th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '5th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '4th Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '3rd Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '2nd Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = '1st Grade'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = 'Kindergaten'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -eq ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = 'Pre-K'}
elseif  ($group.extensionattribute1 -ne ++$TempYear) {$TempClass = "Student Group"}

Set-ADgroup $group.name -description $TempClass  -Replace @{extensionattribute2 = $TempClass}
}
#endregion


    #region this works through the "Student Email Groups"

    $EmailGroups = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase  `
    "ou=student email groups,ou=student groups,ou=groups,ou=kippdelta,dc=deltacollegeprep,dc=org" -filter * -Properties * |   `
    Where-Object {$_.description -like "class*"} |
    select Name, description, extensionattribute2, extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute3




    #Checks the ExtAtt3 flag, updates ExtAtt1 and desc if SchoolYear has changed
    foreach ($mygroup in $emailgroups){

          #Resets ExtAtt3 to 0 if before July 1
             if ($yearchange -eq 0) {Set-ADGroup $mygroup.name -Replace @{extensionattribute3 = 0}}


          #Sets ExtAtt1 to the next year if past July and Extatt3 is still 0

            if (($yearchange -eq "1") -and ($mygroup.extensionattribute3 -eq "0")) {`

            $newatt1 = [int]$mygroup.extensionAttribute1 + [int]1 
            $newDesc = "Class of "+ $newatt1

            Set-ADGroup $mygroup.name -description $newDesc -Replace @{extensionattribute1 = $newatt1 }
            $mygroup.extensionAttribute1 = $newatt1


          #Updates "Student Email Groups" description and updates group memebers

            {switch -Wildcard ($mygroup.name )
               {
               "DELA*"  {switch -Wildcard ($mygroup.name)
                        {
                        "*12*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*11*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*10*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*9*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*8*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*7*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*6*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*5*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*4*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*3*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*2*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*1*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*Kin*"{$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*pre-k*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        }
                        }

                "DCPS*" {switch -Wildcard ($mygroup.name)
                        {
                        "*12*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*11*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*10*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*9*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*8*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*7*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*6*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*5*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*4*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*3*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*2*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*1*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*Kin*"{$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*pre-k*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                         Default {}
                        }
                        }

                "DCHS*" {switch -Wildcard ($mygroup.name)
                        {
                        "*12*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*11*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*10*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*9*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*8*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*7*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*6*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*5*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*4*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*3*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*2*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*1*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*Kin*"{$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*pre-k*" {$mygroup.description = ("Helena class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                         Default {}
                        }
                        }

                "BCPS*" {switch -Wildcard ($mygroup.name)
                        {
                        "*12*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*11*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*10*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*9*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*8*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*7*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*6*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*5*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*4*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*3*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*2*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*1*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*Kin*"{$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*pre-k*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                         Default {}
                        }
                        }

                "KBC*"  {switch -Wildcard ($mygroup.name)
                        {
                        "*12*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*11*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*10*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*9*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*8*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*7*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*6*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*5*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*4*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*3*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*2*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*1*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*Kin*"{$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*pre-k*" {$mygroup.description = ("Blytheville class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                         Default {}
                        }
                        }

                "FCCPS*"{switch -Wildcard ($mygroup.name)
                        {
                        "*12*" {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*11*" {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*10*" {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*9*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*8*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*7*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*6*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*5*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*4*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*3*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*2*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*1*"  {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*Kin*"{$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                        "*pre-k*" {$mygroup.description = ("Forrest City class of "+ $mygroup.extensionAttribute1)}
                         Default {}
                        }
                        }
                }
            }


            Remove-ADGroupMember $mygroup.name -Members (Get-ADGroupMember $mygroup.name) -Confirm:$false 
            Add-ADGroupMember $mygroup.name $mygroup.description
            Set-ADGroup $mygroup.name -Replace @{extensionattribute3 = 1}
            }
     }   

    #endregion
```